# Allowing User to Select off of Partial Records in a Continuous Form in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I am creating a form in access to allow users to input multiple production records for a day.

The form is set as a continuous data entry form and has data validation in place to ensure the information being entered is consistent.

I am having a problem where if a user starts typing something on a new entry, they essentially have no way to back out of it or cancel the entry without completely filling out the form.

I want to keep the data validation to ensure the data being recorded is accurate, but also do not want to lock users into an entry unless it is completely filled out.

I think the ideal would be to allow users to create a new record or select other records without needing to save the current record.

If it would be possible to make it so records only save when a button at the top of the form is pressed I think that would be ideal, but I have not found a good way to do this without requiring it on every single entry.

I have attached a picture of what I am talking about, there could be various error messages but essentially if you try to click off when a record is incomplete it will give an error until the entire form is filled out.

***Example of Error Message and Image of Continuous Form***

[image]

Comment: As long as the record hasn't been saved, the user can cancel by pressing Esc one or more times.  That's the default method.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, that should work for most cases! Do you know of a way to get a similar result without the contents being erased? So that essentially it would  'deselect' without saving but still save what had been entered up to that point.

Comment: The record is not written to the table until the user leaves the form, navigates to a new record, or you perhaps have a save button on the form (me.Dirty = false is the code to save). So, just sitting on a form and typing in data does not write to the table. So, it is  question of what you do or allow (navigate to another record = save, or close form = save. But, you can have the form close without a save too.

Comment: ValidationRule can be set up to allow Null. So like: `.... Or Is Null`, This will allow user to leave that control empty and move on to next. Use form BeforeUpdate event to validate required fields. I am not familiar with that error message.

Comment: "allow users to create a new record or select other records without needing to save the current record" doesn't quite make sense. Why would user open another record or start another new record before deciding what to do with one already in progress?

Comment: June the idea was basically just for situations where for the exception case where a user has partial information on something and wants to fill in what they know for now. After reading everyone's comments I think that it is enough of a fringe case that we will just have to explain to the user that they have to fill out everything or nothing, so just hitting escape as Gustav explained would be fine. We wouldn't want to allow null values to be saved because it would cause issues when uploading to our MRP system later.

Answer (score 0):

> 'deselect' without saving but still save what had been entered up to
> that point.

That you can simulate by setting the DefaultValue of each control in the AfterUpdate event of each control:

```
Me!SomeTextBox.DefaultValue = Nz(Me!SomeTextBox.Value)
```

However, I'm not sure that will be a good idea. And you may have to reset the default values when opening the form.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Gustav, I think I will go with your original suggestion, upon further consideration I agree that it would likely just end up causing more issues when it should be a pretty rare case to begin with.